# how to get disks on a PERC H310 visible again

Tags: ubuntu, mdadm, lsi

My setup : small home server with Asrock H67M-ITX, CPU : i3-2120T, PERC H310 RAID with 7 disks all passthrough (I use MDADM for the raid functionality). The system (Ubuntu 20.04) is on a SSD connected to the MB SATA.

Just got a new CPU : E3-1275 v2

I did change the CPU and to have it work, I had to update MB BIOS from v1.30 to v2.20.

Now, when I arrive in Ubuntu, the disks connected to the LSI H310 are not visible at all. the LSI BIOS shows the 7 disks properly.

I have no idea where to start looking. How should I start debug.

Should I update the LSI BIOS too?

***Edit 1*** :
output of `lspci` shows the LSI card (3rd from the end)

```
user@server:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Desktop SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 RAID bus controller: Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon] (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
04:00.0 USB controller: Etron Technology, Inc. EJ168 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
```

***Edit 2 :*** From the LSI BIOS, I have the following info

```
Product Name : PERC H310 Adapter
Package : 20.10.2-0002
FW Version : 2.120.14-1504
BIOS Version : 4.29.00_4.12.05.00_0x05110000
Boot Block Version : 2.02.00.00-0001
Security Capable : No
Controller ID : 0
PCI Bus : 0x01
PCI Device : 0x00
PCI Function : 0x00
PCI Slot ID : 0x11
```

Comment: Ended up being some sort of bad connection in the SAS/SATA cables. I took the Adapter out to log in the serial number, when I plugged it back, it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first. Recheck all the connection.

In that case, it was most likely a bad connection somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The PERC H310 is a RAID controller. In order to use the disks you've connected to it, you must set up virtual disks either in the RAID BIOS, with the MegaRaid Storage Manager for Linux which runs on the Linux desktop GUI, or with the MegaCli command line tool. The virtual disks you set up will appear in Linux as `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` et seq.

Comment: the thing was working before my incident and is working again now. I have no VD set on the PERC H310